# Sending byte array through a Udp Socket and Bitconverter

Tags: c#, sockets, server, udp, bitconverter

I'm attempting to run a simple Udp Server and Client, but receiving incorrect data on the client side.

On the **server** the byte array is constructed with this method:

```
        public byte[] CreateReplyPacket(byte[] data) {

        List<byte> dataStream = new List<byte>();
        userCommand = (Globals.Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);

        switch (userCommand) {

            case Globals.Command.Connect:

                dataStream.Clear();
                dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)userCommand));
                Console.WriteLine("Incoming Connection ...");

                break;

            case Globals.Command.Login:

                int usernameLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);
                int passwordLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);

                if (usernameLength > 0)
                    username = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12, usernameLength);

                if (passwordLength > 0)
                    password = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12 + usernameLength, passwordLength);

                bool loginAttempt = Database.LoginAttempt(username, password);

                dataStream.Clear();
                dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)userCommand));
                dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(loginAttempt));

                break;
        }

        return dataStream.ToArray();
    }
```

Simulating an unsuccessful login attempt, the byte array I get is 01-00-00-00-00. An integer followed by a boolean, which is exactly what want. The boolean is the last 00 which means false.

But on the Client, I get this instead: 01-00-00-00-07. I have no idea what the 7 is, but it's turning my boolean from false to true which obviously is very bad.

Here's the **client** code that handles the incoming byte array:

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult AR) {

    int rec = clientSocket.EndReceiveFrom(AR, ref epServer);

    byte[] tmpData = new byte[rec];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData, 0, tmpData, 0, rec);

    Debug.Log(BitConverter.ToString(tmpData));

    Globals.Command cmdReceived = (Globals.Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(tmpData, 0);

    if (cmdReceived == Globals.Command.Connect) {

        messageToDisplay = "Connected to the Server";

    } else if (cmdReceived == Globals.Command.Login) {

        if (BitConverter.ToBoolean(tmpData, 4)) {

            messageToDisplay = "Succesfully Logged in";
            isAuthenticated = true;
        } else {
            messageToDisplay = "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
    }

    clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epServer, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
}
```

This is a very new concept to me, and my first post to StackOverflow, so I must apologize the answer is obvious. Or if I've left out anything else important in my code.

Comment: And what is byteData in client code? I mean I don't see  how it is declared / filled.

Comment: private byte[] byteData = new byte[8192];

Comment: and filled: clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epServer, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);

Comment: is that enough info? or do you want the entire client code?

Comment: Well not sure what's wrong exaclty, but code leaves strange impression. Why don't you use UdpClient class and work with raw sockets? Why shared buffer (byteData)?

Comment: A strange impression? lol that's putting it nicely. I will try that and see if I get different results. Thanks!

Comment: The first think is the OnReceive may not get all the data in one chunk.  So you have to make sure you get the entire message before decoding.  There are three method you can use 1) Terminate the message with a terminating character not inside the message. 2) Add a byte count to beginning of each message then read until you get the terminating character 3) Send fixed lenght messages.

Comment: OK Finally figured it out thanks to Evk asking me about the shared buffer. That is what was causing the problem. I now have an outgoing and an incoming buffer and it seems to work fine. Thanks so much!